# Cannot convert value of type NSSet? to expected argument type Set<HKSampleType>

Tags: ios, swift

I just started learning swift 2 days ago so I apologise in advance if this may sound like a dumb question.

I'm working on getting the basic user data from HealthKit following this tutorial: https://www.natashatherobot.com/healthkit-getting-fitness-data/
but when I compile it, I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type NSSet? to expected argument type
>   Set <'HKSampleType>

```
func requestHealthKitAuthorization(dataTypesToWrite: NSSet?, dataTypesToRead: NSSet?) {
    healthStore?.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(dataTypesToWrite, readTypes: dataTypesToRead, completion: { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            println("success")
        } else {
            println(error.description)
        }
    })
}
```

I have tried various answers that I found online but without success.

Any tip/idea would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have find an old article written in Swift 1 era, a long, long time ago.
And I assume you are using the latest released version of Xcode (7.3.1, including Swift 2.2.1).

The method showing the error can be rewritten like this:

```
func requestHealthKitAuthorization(dataTypesToWrite: Set<HKSampleType>?, dataTypesToRead: Set<HKObjectType>?) {
    healthStore?.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(dataTypesToWrite, readTypes: dataTypesToRead, completion: { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            print("success")
        } else {
            print(error?.description ?? "unknown error")
        }
    })
}
```

- The two types of first two parameters have changed to `Set<HKSampleType>?` and `Set<HKObjectType>?`.
  (The error message is indicating the first mismatching.)
- The optionality for the `completion` handler's parameters has changed.
- `println` and `print` are unified to new `print`.

But you may (very probably) find many other difficulties following the ancient article.

I recommend you to **find another article written for the same version of Xcode/Swift you are using**.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast `NSSet` to Swift `Set`

```
if let writeDataTypes = dataTypesToWrite as? Set<HKSampleType>,
       readDataTypes = dataTypesToRead as? Set<HKSampleType> { ...
```